# If I have merged a Git branch to master, can I delete the branch itself?

Tags: git, version-control

If I have a [feature branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-feature-branch) that has been merged into the master branch and will never be needed as a separate branch again, can I delete the feature branch from the local repo and the origin repo?

Comment: As long as the branch history was not lost when you merged, there shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete a local git branch:

```
git branch -D <branch_name>
```

Delete remote git branch:

```
git push origin --delete <branch_name>
```

If the question is whether it would be a problem: No, if all commits are merged.

Comment: the git push - how does it know the current branch?  does this delete the current branch?

Comment: since I'm new here, I didn't know that it would interpret html tags ... even if they are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can delete the single feature branch:

```
# Delete a single branch that has already been completed locally and then remotely

$ git branch -D my-feature-branch
$ git push origin :my-feature-branch
```

Alternatively, you can delete all feature branches that have been merged into an integration branch:

```
# The following command deletes all LOCAL branches that have been merged into the current commit, where the branch name starts with 'feature', except for branch 'integration'.
# You will need to remove the 'echo' to actually run it.

$ git branch --merged | grep -i feature | grep -v integration | xargs -i echo git branch -D {}

# The following command deletes all REMOTE branches that have been merged into the current commit, where the branch name starts with 'feature', except for branch 'integration'.
# You will need to remove the 'echo' to actually run it.

$ git branch -r --merged | grep -i feature | grep -v integration | cut -d '/' -f 2 | xargs -n 1 echo git push --delete origin

# The following command deletes all REMOTE branches that have been merged into master
# You will need to remove the 'echo' to actually run it.

$ git checkout master
$ git merge origin/master --ff-only
$ git branch -r --merged | grep -v master | cut -d '/' -f 2 | xargs -n 1 echo git push --delete origin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think you've merged the branch, then it's perfectly safe to delete using `git branch -d <branchName>` or `git branch --delete <branchName>`, as they won't delete a branch that hasn't been merged. The lowercase `d` will cause git to warn you if the branch hasn't merged the branch, but if you want to delete a branch without keeping the most recent commits, then `git branch -D` will force a delete.

To delete a remote branch, use `git push origin :<branchName>`, or `git push origin --delete <branchName>`.